# Unordered Map with a custom class

Tags: c++, unordered-map

im new here and this is my first question..
(I found some answers to my question while looking at this site, but i dont understand what they mean since mine is a tiny bit different.)
Let me first show you some code:
So this is my class:

```
class citems{
public:
    char* name;
    int colorR;
    int colorG;
    int colorB;
    int type;

citems(char* name, int colorR, int colorG, int colorB, int type)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->colorR = colorR;
    this->colorG = colorG;
    this->colorB = colorB;
    this->type = type;
}
};
```

And then i would make a function like to do this, but with a long list:

```
citems getObjectFromId(int ID)
{
static unordered_map <int, citems> item;
static bool init = false;
if (!init)
{
item[123546]= citems("Name", 181,179, 0, 9);
init = true;
}
return item[ID];
}
```

So i could just call the item ID and in return get the separate colors, type and name at any time.
Everything ok so far, but when i compile i get this error:

> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   11.0\vc\include\unordered_map(239): error C2228: left of '.first' must have class/struct/union

So i read i have to make my own EqualOperator or something like that but i can't seem to get a logic from it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For `T& operator[]( const Key& key )` mapped type has to meet [DefaultConstructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/DefaultConstructible) requirement. This means your class citems needs a default constructor:

```
class citems{
public:
    //...

    /* possible form 1 */
    citems() {
    }

    /* possible form 2 ( default parameter values)*/
    citems( char* name = 0, int colorR = -1, int colorG = -1,
                              int colorB = -1, int type = -1) {
    }
};
```

Note also that `T& operator[]( const Key& key )` returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, performing an insertion if such key does not already exist. If you don't want to insert new element when there's no given key in the map but to change existing one - you have first to check if such element is present on map using `find()` or inserting with `insert()`.